# Multiple HighCharts Spline Charts On Same Webpage Causes Plotlines to Disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have two Highcharts spline charts that are being loaded with 30 minutes of data. I am using SignalR to add the last reading to both charts once a minute. If I just have one chart on the page, everything works fine. If I add a second spline chart, the initial 30 minute load renders the chart correctly. But when I have two charts on the page and the subsequent first added point update occurs, **the plotlines disappear**. I have tried using setTimeout to redraw the charts instead of calling it directly but to no avail.

The original 30 minutes worth of data call is: series.addPoint([time, value], false, false) with a subsequent chart.redraw() after all the points are plotted.

The single point call is: series.addPoint([time, value], true, true),

Any ideas?

Comment: Please replicate your example as live demo.

Comment: Do you mean `plotLines` or do you mean the data points? Have you verified that your charts have unique IDs and are rendered to the correct DIV? Is your single point call adding the point to the correct chart?

Comment: I am certain the DIV is correct, but where do you set a Chart ID?

Comment: Is the chart ID the same as the chart renderTo container name?

Comment: Thanks for your help. You didn't fix it directly, but by checking the id of the chart I was updating, I discovered I was calling the method I have to add points two extra times and passed a null value. That was my problem. Thanks.